# How to use right associative op in the expression?

Tags: haskell, operators, associativity

I've defined my own operator:

```
infixr 6 >+
x >+ y = (+ x) y
```

It is right associative.

And now I want to use in the next expression:

```
(`mod` 14) (>+ 5) 10
```

But I get an error:

```
<interactive>:11:1:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Integral (a -> a)
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
      it :: forall a. (Integral (a -> a), Num a) => a
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: None of the code you've provided does anything about right associativity.  Right associativity only does something when you use a function infix.  Function application _always_ has the highest precedence.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Now I understand where the OP's confusion stems from!

Comment: I think the OP expects `(>+ 5)` to apply to `10` before `(\`mod\` 14)`, but that's never going to happen, basically.

Comment: Associativity rules essentially let you omit a few parentheses in expressions like `x + y - z * w << a`, involving infix operators. Nothing more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not how associativity works.

Associativity defines the behavior of chained operation with the same operator.

For example, when an operator * is left associative, then `a * b * c * d` is evaluated as `((a * b) * c) * d`.

If * is right associative, then it will be evaluated as `a * (b * (c * d))`

In conclusion, your `>+` does nothing since addition is commutative. That is, `a + b + c` is equivalent to `a >+ b >+ c` since `(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)`.

In Haskell you can also define non-associative operators. It means that the operations cannot be chained, or your compiler will raise a parse error.